# How to add a new thread for executing particular function in ASP.NET website?

Tags: .net, asp.net, multithreading, .net-3.5

In my website, I want to create a separate thread for a process which needs to constantly run in the background. I want to use threading so that my website performance is not degraded.

I want to create thread for following code.

```
  [WebMethod]
    public void iterativeFunction()
    {
        int count = 0;
        DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2011,5,31);
        while (System.DateTime.Compare(System.DateTime.Now,date1)<0)
        {
            downloadAndParse();

            count++;
        }
    }
```

How should I add a new thread for this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
public static class BackgroundHelper
{
    private static readonly object _syncRoot = new object();
    private static readonly ManualResetEvent _event = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static Thread _thread;

    public static bool Running { get; private set; }

    public static void Start()
    {
        lock (_syncRoot)
        {
            if (Running)
                return;

            Running = true;

            // Reset the event so we can use it to stop the thread.
            _event.Reset();

            // Star the background thread.
            _thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(BackgroundProcess));
            _thread.Start();
        }
    }

    public static void Stop()
    {
        lock (_syncRoot)
        {
            if (!Running)
                return;

            Running = false;

            // Signal the thread to stop.
            _event.Set();

            // Wait for the thread to have stopped.
            _thread.Join();
            _thread = null;
        }
    }

    private static void BackgroundProcess()
    {
        int count = 0;
        DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2011, 5, 31);
        while (System.DateTime.Compare(System.DateTime.Now, date1) < 0)
        {
            downloadAndParse();

            // Wait for the event to be set with a maximum of the timeout. The
            // timeout is used to pace the calls to downloadAndParse so that
            // it not goes to 100% when there is nothing to download and parse.
            bool result = _event.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

            // If the event was set, we're done processing.
            if (result)
                break;

            count++;
        }
    }

    private static void downloadAndParse()
    {
        // Your download and parse logic here.
    }
}
```

Then in your web service:

```
[WebMethod]
public void iterativeFunction()
{
    BackgroundHelper.Start();
}
```

Comment: @Pieter : Ok Thanks I will get back you as soon as I will try your code. Thanks for the input though. :)

Comment: @Pieter: As such it works but I am not sure that the while loop continues the execution once the browser is closed. I want that it should continue even when there is no active broswer session. How should I do that?

Comment: @PARTH - There is no relation, at all, between the request and the thread. ASP.NET cannot detect that you've started a thread. Because of this, it just keeps on running. If for testing you want to be sure, you could e.g. do a `File.WriteAllText("C:\\Users\\YourName\\Log.txt", DateTime.Now.ToString())`.

Comment: @Pieter: Thanks for being so helpful. :) How can I stop this thread or kill the thread in between?

Comment: @PARTH - That's where the `BackgroundHelper.Stop()` method is for. You can create a second web service for this.

Comment: @Pieter: I am not clear about the role of this line ` bool result = _event.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));` Can you please explain a bit on what it does?

Comment: @PARTH - This line has two jobs. The first (the reason the result is taken) is to verify whether the background process has to shut down. The second is to stagger your background process. The reason you want to do this is that e.g. when the method does not have any work to do, and it returns immediately, you would have 100% CPU usage with a background process doing nothing. You should at least set this to `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)` to have the method run every second, or `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)` to have it run every minute.

Comment: oK Pieter. Thanks for the help. Now When I tried added `BackgroundHelper.Stop()` in a webservice and tried calling that service method on button click then it takes to much time to stop the thread. Why would it be so slow?

Comment: @PARTH - Most likely because the `downloadAndParse` method is still busy. If it's an option, you can periodically check for the status of `Running` in `downloadAndParse` and abort the process if you see that flag becomes `false`.

Comment: Even it doesnt stop the existing thread. I have two buttons start and stop. Start button starts the thread and i need to break or kill the running thread on Stop button. But even after stopping the thread using BackgroundHelper.Stop() the thread doesnt seem to stop. What could be wrong?

Comment: @PARTH - I'm not sure. The code should work and this depends on the rest of your application. I'm sorry but I believe I cannot help you further.